# Setting iOS "Launch Screen File" from CMake

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake

I am developing an iOS project using Xcode 8, and the project is generated via CMake. In CMake, you can specify the `AppIcon` and `LaunchImage` with the `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME` and `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME`. These correspond to the Xcode attributes (with the `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_` prefix), in the Xcode project.

However, it doesn't seem that the launch screen file is saved as a similar attribute. In fact, I don't see how it is saved at all - modifying it apparently doesn't change the project.pbxproj file at all. Is there any way to specify the file during CMake generation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `UILaunchStoryboardName` to your `info.plist` file. It should work

Comment: If you're editing the `info.plist` file in Xcode, this option is called `Launch screen interface file base name` & the value should be formatted `<Launch Storyboard Name>.storyboard`.